# Problem with JScrollBar Display

Tags: java, swing

I have added the following code for displaying a scrollbar to my textfield. But it still does not appear. Can someone please help me with this problem. I am unable to figure out where error is occuring:

```
public JTextArea talkArea = new JTextArea();

public JScrollPane talkAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(talkArea);

this.getContentPane(talkArea,null);

this.getContentPane(talkAreaScrollPane,null);
```

The code for the whole file is as follows and it compiles properly without giving error:

```
/*
 * Client.java
 *
 */

package ChatClientRMI;

import javax.naming.*;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;

import ChatServerRMI.*;

import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener {

  private static final String connectStr = "Connect";
  private static final String disconnectStr = "Disonnect";

  private String _nickname;
  private Thread _thread;
  private Context _initialContext;
  private JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
  public JTextArea talkArea = new JTextArea;

  JScrollPane talkAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(talkArea);

  private JButton _connectButton;
  private JButton _disconnectButton;

  private Vector serverVector = new Vector();
  private JList serverList = new JList(serverVector);

  ChatRoom chatroom = null;
  String chatroomName;

  Client myFrame = this;
  MyActionListener myActionListener = new MyActionListener();

  boolean loaded = false;

  static int REFRESH_TIME = 200;

  // a timer for refresh graphic area
  javax.swing.Timer frameTimer =
    new javax.swing.Timer(REFRESH_TIME, myActionListener);

  // client area info
  public static int CLIENT_WIDTH = 800;
  public static int CLIENT_HEIGHT = 600;

  // left panel info
  public static int LEFT_PANEL_WIDTH = 120;
  public static int LEFT_PANEL_HEIGHT = 420;
  public static int LEFT_PANEL_LEFT = 20;
  public static int LEFT_PANEL_TOP = 20;

  // graphic area info
  public static int GRAPHIC_TOP = 30;
  public static int GRAPHIC_LEFT = 30;
  public static int GRAPHIC_WIDTH = 400;
  public static int GRAPHIC_HEIGHT = 300;

  // talk area info
  public static int TALK_TOP = GRAPHIC_TOP + GRAPHIC_HEIGHT + 5;
  public static int TALK_LEFT = GRAPHIC_LEFT;
  public static int TALK_WIDTH = GRAPHIC_WIDTH;
  public static int TALK_HEIGHT = 175;

  // input field info
  public static int INPUT_TOP = TALK_TOP + TALK_HEIGHT + 25;
  public static int INPUT_LEFT = GRAPHIC_LEFT;
  public static int INPUT_WIDTH = GRAPHIC_WIDTH;
  public static int INPUT_HEIGHT = 20;

  // server list info
  public static int SERVER_LIST_TOP = GRAPHIC_TOP;
  public static int SERVER_LIST_LEFT = GRAPHIC_LEFT + GRAPHIC_WIDTH + 160;
  public static int SERVER_LIST_WIDTH = 120;
  public static int SERVER_LIST_HEIGHT = GRAPHIC_HEIGHT; // 420;

  // user list info
  public static int USER_LIST_TOP = 20;
  public static int USER_LIST_LEFT = GRAPHIC_LEFT + GRAPHIC_WIDTH + 10;
  public static int USER_LIST_WIDTH = 120;
  public static int USER_LIST_HEIGHT = 420;

  public static int SHADOW_WIDTH = 5;

  // background color
  static Color backColor = new Color(130, 60, 170);

  // command label
  static final String CMD_LABEL[] =
    { "change icon", "query friend", "change location", "open room",
      "query hero", "help", "temp leave", "leave" };

  // icon info
  public static final int MAX_ICONS = 100;
  public static final String ICON_FILENAME = "icons.gif";
  public static int ICON_WIDTH = 32;
  public static int ICON_HEIGHT = 32;
  Image icons[] = new Image[MAX_ICONS];
  int totalIcons = 16;

  static String BACKIMG_FILENAME[] =
    { "back0.jpg", "back1.jpg", "back2.jpg", "back3.jpg" };

  Image backImg = null;
  Image leftPanelImg = null;
  Image graphicImg = null;
  Image userListImg = null;
  Image serverListImg = null;

  // user info
  static int MAX_USERS = 100;
  UserInfo userInfo[] = new UserInfo[MAX_USERS];
  int totalUsers = 0;
  int myIdx = 0;
  Hashtable users = new Hashtable();

  // say delay
  static int SAY_TIME = 15;

  // say rectangle's width
  static int SAY_WIDTH = 100;

  // move step
  static int ONE_STEP = 10;

  boolean endChat = true;
  boolean moveEnd = true;
  boolean sayEnd = true;

  int enterListIndex = -1;
  int exitListIndex = -1;

  /** Creates new ChatClient */
  public Client(String name) {
    super(name);
    _nickname = name;
    try {
      _initialContext = new InitialContext();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    // Create and install a security manager
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
      System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }

    setSize(new Dimension(CLIENT_WIDTH, CLIENT_HEIGHT));
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(backColor);

    talkArea.setEditable(false);
    talkArea.setBackground(Color.white);
    talkArea.setBounds(new Rectangle(TALK_LEFT, TALK_TOP, TALK_WIDTH,
      TALK_HEIGHT));
    this.getContentPane().add(talkArea, null);

    // set input area
    inputField.setBackground(Color.white);
    inputField.setBounds(new Rectangle(INPUT_LEFT, INPUT_TOP, INPUT_WIDTH,
      INPUT_HEIGHT));

    inputField.addActionListener(this);
    this.getContentPane().add(inputField, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(talkAreaScrollPane, null);

    // connect button
    _connectButton = new JButton(connectStr);
    _connectButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(600, 400, 100, 30));
    _connectButton.addActionListener(this);
    this.getContentPane().add(_connectButton);

    // disconnect button
    _disconnectButton = new JButton(disconnectStr);
    _disconnectButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(600, 450, 100, 30));
    _disconnectButton.setEnabled(false);
    // _disconnectButton.addActionListener(this);
    this.getContentPane().add(_disconnectButton);

    // testButton = new JButton("test");
    // testButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(600,500,100,30));
    // testButton.addActionListener(this);
    // this.getContentPane().add(testButton);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      serverVector.add("ChatRoom" + i);
    }

    serverList.setBackground(new Color(190, 180, 255));
    serverList.setBounds(new Rectangle(SERVER_LIST_LEFT + 2,
      SERVER_LIST_TOP + 40, SERVER_LIST_WIDTH - SHADOW_WIDTH - 10,
      SERVER_LIST_HEIGHT - 40 - 50));
    serverList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    serverList.setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
    this.getContentPane().add(serverList);

    // add mouse listener for serverList
    serverList.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        int index = serverList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
        enterListIndex = index;
        // setForeground(new Color(0,0,255));
        System.out.println("you entered index " + index);
      }

      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        int index = serverList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
        exitListIndex = index;
        // setForeground(new Color(0,255,255));
        System.out.println("you exited index " + index);
      }
    });

    // add mouse listener
    this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
      public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent event) {
        mouseClick_performed(event);
      }
    });

    // Always need this to enable closing the frame
    this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
        if (endChat) {
          System.exit(0);
          return;
        }
        boolean success = false;
        try {
          success = chatroom.disconnect(_nickname);
        } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException err) {
          System.out.println(err);
        }
        if (success)
          System.out.println("Disonnected...");
        else
          System.out.println("Not disconnected.");

        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    // Wait for incoming requests
    this.startThread();

    // Enable GUI
    this.setVisible(true);

    // create offscreen images
    leftPanelImg = createImage(LEFT_PANEL_WIDTH, LEFT_PANEL_HEIGHT);
    graphicImg = createImage(GRAPHIC_WIDTH, GRAPHIC_HEIGHT);
    userListImg = createImage(USER_LIST_WIDTH, USER_LIST_HEIGHT);
    serverListImg = createImage(SERVER_LIST_WIDTH, SERVER_LIST_HEIGHT);

    drawServerList();
    serverList.repaint();

    (new LoadImageThread()).load();

    try {
      _initialContext.rebind(_nickname, new ChatUserImpl(this));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

  }

  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if (source == _connectButton) {
      if (serverList.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "please select a chatroom",
          "Error Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
      }
      _connectButton.removeActionListener(this);
      _connectButton.setEnabled(false);
      _disconnectButton.addActionListener(this);
      _disconnectButton.setEnabled(true);
      inputField.addActionListener(this);

      chatroomName = (String) serverList.getSelectedValue();
      int code = (new Random()).nextInt(totalIcons - 1);
      boolean success = false;
      try {

        System.out.println("chat room name: " + chatroomName);
        chatroom =
          (ChatRoom) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(_initialContext
            .lookup(chatroomName), ChatRoom.class);
        success = chatroom.connect(_nickname, code);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ChatUserClient exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (success) {
        System.out.println("Connected...");
        endChat = false;
        frameTimer.start();
      } else {
        System.out
          .println("Not connected: the selected nickname is in use. Please choose another nickname.");
      }
    } else if (source == _disconnectButton) {

      _connectButton.addActionListener(this);
      _connectButton.setEnabled(true);
      _disconnectButton.removeActionListener(this);
      _disconnectButton.setEnabled(false);
      inputField.removeActionListener(this);

      // clear everything
      talkArea.setText("");
      inputField.setText("");

      if (backImg == null) {
        Graphics g = graphicImg.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GRAPHIC_WIDTH, GRAPHIC_HEIGHT);
        getGraphics().drawImage(graphicImg, GRAPHIC_LEFT, GRAPHIC_TOP, this);
      } else {
        getGraphics().drawImage(backImg, GRAPHIC_LEFT, GRAPHIC_TOP, this);
      }

      users.clear();

      if (endChat) {
        return;
      }

      boolean success = false;
      try {
        success = chatroom.disconnect(_nickname);
      } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
      if (success) {
        endChat = true;
        System.out.println("Disonnected...");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Not disconnected.");
      }

    } else if (source == inputField) {
      String message = inputField.getText();
      try {
        chatroom.sendMessage(message, _nickname);
      } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  } // end actionperformed

  public void startThread() {
    _thread = new Thread(this);
    _thread.start();
  }

  public void run() {

  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    if (loaded) {
      g.drawImage(graphicImg, GRAPHIC_LEFT, GRAPHIC_TOP, this);
      g.drawImage(serverListImg, SERVER_LIST_LEFT, SERVER_LIST_TOP, this);
      serverList.repaint();
    }
  }

  // sgn func
  public int sgn(int x) {
    if (x > 0)
      return 1;
    if (x < 0)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }

  // everyone move one step
  public void moveOneStep() {
    int count = 0;
    int direction;

    for (Enumeration e = users.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
      UserInfo p = (UserInfo) e.nextElement();

      direction = sgn(p.dx - p.x);
      if (direction == 0)
        count++;
      p.x += direction * ONE_STEP;
      direction = sgn(p.dy - p.y);
      if (direction == 0)
        count++;
      p.y += direction * ONE_STEP;

      if (java.lang.Math.abs(p.x - p.dx) <= ONE_STEP)
        p.x = p.dx;
      if (java.lang.Math.abs(p.y - p.dy) <= ONE_STEP)
        p.y = p.dy;

      if (p.x <= ICON_WIDTH / 2) {
        p.x = ICON_WIDTH / 2;
        p.dx = p.x;
      }
      if (p.x >= GRAPHIC_WIDTH - ICON_WIDTH / 2) {
        p.x = GRAPHIC_WIDTH - ICON_WIDTH / 2;
        p.dx = p.x;
      }
      if (p.y <= ICON_HEIGHT / 2) {
        p.y = ICON_HEIGHT / 2;
        p.dy = p.y;
      }
      if (p.y >= GRAPHIC_HEIGHT - ICON_HEIGHT / 2) {
        p.y = GRAPHIC_HEIGHT - ICON_HEIGHT / 2;
        p.dy = p.y;
      }
    }

    moveEnd = (count == users.size() * 2);
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
    System.out.println("size = " + users.size());
    System.out.println("messgeEnd = " + moveEnd);
  } // end of moveOneStep

  // timer action
  public void timer_actionPerformed() {
    if (endChat)
      return;
    if (!moveEnd)
      moveOneStep();
    if (moveEnd && sayEnd)
      return;
    drawGraphicArea();
    getGraphics().drawImage(graphicImg, GRAPHIC_LEFT, GRAPHIC_TOP, this);
  }

  // mouse event
  public void mouseClick_performed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent event) {
    if (endChat)
      return;
    // if (endChat == true || myIdx == -1) return;
    // if (userInfo[myIdx].x < 0) return;
    if (event.getID() == event.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
      int x = event.getX();
      int y = event.getY();
      if (x < GRAPHIC_LEFT || x >= GRAPHIC_LEFT + GRAPHIC_WIDTH
        || y < GRAPHIC_TOP || y > GRAPHIC_TOP + GRAPHIC_HEIGHT)
        return;

      moveEnd = false;
      UserInfo p = (UserInfo) users.get(_nickname);
      p.dx = x - GRAPHIC_LEFT;
      p.dy = y - GRAPHIC_TOP;

      try {
        chatroom.sendLocation(p.dx, p.dy, p.name);
      } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
      // sendCmd(MsgType.MOVE, userInfo[myIdx].dx, userInfo[myIdx].dy);
    }
  }

  public void printUserList() {
    Enumeration usernames = users.keys();
    while (usernames.hasMoreElements()) {
      System.out.println("user name: " + usernames.nextElement());
    }
  }

  // draw server list
  public void drawServerList() {
    Graphics g = serverListImg.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(backColor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, SERVER_LIST_WIDTH, SERVER_LIST_HEIGHT);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRoundRect(5, 5, SERVER_LIST_WIDTH - SHADOW_WIDTH, SERVER_LIST_HEIGHT
      - SHADOW_WIDTH, 30, 30);
    g.setColor(new Color(190, 180, 255));
    g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, SERVER_LIST_WIDTH - SHADOW_WIDTH, SERVER_LIST_HEIGHT
      - SHADOW_WIDTH, 30, 30);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255));
    g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, SERVER_LIST_WIDTH - SHADOW_WIDTH, SERVER_LIST_HEIGHT
      - SHADOW_WIDTH, 30, 30);

    g.setFont(new Font(g.getFont().getName(), g.getFont().getStyle(), 20));
    g.setColor(Color.black);

    FontMetrics fntM = g.getFontMetrics();
    String s = new String("Server List");
    int x = (SERVER_LIST_WIDTH - fntM.stringWidth(s)) / 2;
    g.drawString(s, x, 30);

    // update to screen
    getGraphics().drawImage(serverListImg, SERVER_LIST_LEFT, SERVER_LIST_TOP,
      this);
  }

  // draw graphic area
  public synchronized void drawGraphicArea() {
    Graphics g = graphicImg.getGraphics();
    FontMetrics fntM = g.getFontMetrics();

    if (backImg == null) {
      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, GRAPHIC_WIDTH, GRAPHIC_HEIGHT);
    } else {
      g.drawImage(backImg, 0, 0, this);
    }
    // if (myIdx == -1) return ;

    UserInfo p;
    g.setFont(new Font(g.getFont().getName(), g.getFont().getStyle(), 12));

    int count = 0;

    for (Enumeration e = users.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
      // draw icon
      p = (UserInfo) e.nextElement();
      g.drawImage(icons[p.code], p.x - ICON_WIDTH / 2, p.y - ICON_HEIGHT / 2,
        this);

      // draw name
      if (p.name.equals(_nickname))
        g.setColor(Color.red);
      else
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      int x = (p.x - fntM.stringWidth(p.name) / 2);
      int y = (p.y + ICON_HEIGHT / 2);
      g.fillRoundRect(x - 2, y, fntM.stringWidth(p.name) + 4, fntM.getHeight(),
        10, 10);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawRoundRect(x - 2, y, fntM.stringWidth(p.name) + 4, fntM.getHeight(),
        10, 10);
      g.drawString(p.name, x, y + fntM.getAscent());

      // draw say
      if (p.sayTime <= 0) {
        count++;
        continue;
      }
      String saySplit[] = new String[100];
      int c = 0;
      int st = 0, ed = 1;
      while (ed <= p.say.length()) {
        String s = p.say.substring(st, ed);
        if (fntM.stringWidth(s) > SAY_WIDTH) {
          saySplit[c] = p.say.substring(st, ed - 1);
          c++;
          st = ed - 1;
        }
        ed++;
      }
      saySplit[c] = p.say.substring(st, ed - 1);
      c++;
      x = p.x + ICON_WIDTH / 2 + 5;
      y = p.y - ICON_HEIGHT / 2 + 5;
      int w = ((c > 1) ? SAY_WIDTH : fntM.stringWidth(saySplit[0])) + 5;
      int h = fntM.getHeight() * c + 5;

      // draw say arrow
      g.setColor(Color.green);
      if (x + w >= GRAPHIC_WIDTH) {
        x = p.x - ICON_WIDTH / 2 - w - 5;
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.addPoint(p.x - ICON_WIDTH / 2, p.y - 5);
        polygon.addPoint(p.x - ICON_WIDTH / 2 - 8, p.y - 10);
        polygon.addPoint(p.x - ICON_WIDTH / 2 - 8, p.y - 4);
        // p.addPoint(x + ICON_WIDTH/2, y - 5);
        g.fillPolygon(polygon);
      } else {
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.addPoint(p.x + ICON_WIDTH / 2, p.y - 5);
        polygon.addPoint(p.x + ICON_WIDTH / 2 + 8, p.y - 10);
        polygon.addPoint(p.x + ICON_WIDTH / 2 + 8, p.y - 4);
        // p.addPoint(x + ICON_WIDTH/2, y - 5);
        g.fillPolygon(polygon);
      }

      g.fillRoundRect(x, y, w, h, 10, 10);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      // g.drawRoundRect(x, y, w, h, 10, 10);
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        g.drawString(saySplit[j], x + 2, y + 2 + j * fntM.getHeight()
          + fntM.getAscent());
      }
      p.sayTime--;
    } // end of for
    sayEnd = (count == users.size());

    update(getGraphics());
  } // end of drawGraphicArea

  class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object obj = e.getSource();
      if (obj == frameTimer) {
        timer_actionPerformed();
        return;
      }

    }
  }

  // ****************************************
  // a load image thread class in applet class
  // ****************************************
  class LoadImageThread extends Thread {
    public void load() {
      this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
      loadImages();
      loaded = true;
      try {
        sleep(1000);
      } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
      }
      if (backImg == null) {
        Graphics g = graphicImg.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GRAPHIC_WIDTH, GRAPHIC_HEIGHT);
        (myFrame.getGraphics()).drawImage(graphicImg, GRAPHIC_LEFT,
          GRAPHIC_TOP, myFrame);
      } else {
        myFrame.getGraphics().drawImage(backImg, GRAPHIC_LEFT, GRAPHIC_TOP,
          myFrame);
      }
    }

    // load all images
    public void loadImages() {

      Graphics g = graphicImg.getGraphics();
      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, GRAPHIC_WIDTH, GRAPHIC_HEIGHT);
      g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      g.setFont(new Font(g.getFont().getName(), g.getFont().getStyle(), 30));
      g.drawString("loading, please wait ......", 30, 50);
      (myFrame.getGraphics()).drawImage(graphicImg, GRAPHIC_LEFT, GRAPHIC_TOP,
        myFrame);

      MediaTracker m = new MediaTracker(myFrame);
      for (int i = 0; i < totalIcons; i++) {
        icons[i] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(i + ".gif");
        m.addImage(icons[i], 0);
      }

      try {
        m.waitForAll();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("can't read image from file");
      }

    }

  } // end of LoadImage class

  class CustomCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
      int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

      String s = value.toString();
      setText(s);
      // setIcon((s.length() > 10) ? longIcon : shortIcon);
      if (isSelected) {
        // setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        // setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
      } else {
        // setBackground(list.getBackground());
        // setForeground(list.getForeground());
        setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 255));
      }
      /*
       * if ( index == enterListIndex ){ System.out.println("****************");
       * setForeground(new Color(0,0,180)); } if ( index == exitListIndex ){
       * System.out.println("---------------"); setForeground(new
       * Color(0,255,255)); }
       */
      setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
      setFont(list.getFont());
      return this;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // args[0] is user nickname
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage: ChatClient nickname");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    Client clientFrame = new Client(args[0]);
  }

}
```

Any idea???
Do I need to set any kind of visibility??
Thanks

Comment: Why did you post 200 lines of code??? We don't have time to read all that code. If you have a problem understanding the basics of how something works then create a simple example. All you need is a JFrame with a text area and a scrollpane, about 20 lines of code and it will be easy for you or us to see your mistake. Its called a SSCCE (http://sscce.org). Learn how to use them to help you debug a problem.

Comment: thank you and I apologize for the code. I thought it would help if I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding both the  text area, AND the scrollpane containing it to the content pane.
you're also setting sizes on the textarea, but not the scrollpane.  and since your layout is managing all the bounds, the scrollpane is probably 0x0 at 0,0

```
setSize(new Dimension(CLIENT_WIDTH, CLIENT_HEIGHT));
this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
this.getContentPane().setBackground(backColor);
talkArea.setEditable(false);
talkArea.setBackground(Color.white);
talkArea.setBounds(new Rectangle(TALK_LEFT, TALK_TOP, TALK_WIDTH,      TALK_HEIGHT));
this.getContentPane().add(talkArea, null); // <--- you want this inside the text area, not here!
// set input area
inputField.setBackground(Color.white);
inputField.setBounds(new Rectangle(INPUT_LEFT, INPUT_TOP, INPUT_WIDTH,      INPUT_HEIGHT));
inputField.addActionListener(this);
this.getContentPane().add(inputField, null);
this.getContentPane().add(talkAreaScrollPane, null);  // <--- you never set the size on here
```

why are you getting rid of the layout and then managing everything explicitly for size?  this would be a lot simpler if you used something like borderlayout and preferred sizes and let those things manage bounds for you.

Answer (score 3):

No, add the textArea to the ScrollPane then put the ScrollPane in your panel.

As a side note I would suggest learning more about LayoutManagers.  They are worth the learning curve.

Example:

```
//In a container that uses a BorderLayout:
textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
...
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
...
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
...
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Taken from: [How to use scroll panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: hi.. you mean I just need to add the ScrollPane to the contentPane ?

Comment: You need to put the text area in the scrollpane.  (I just edited the answer with an example).

Comment: i did add the talkArea to the scroll pane. as you have mentioned.

Comment: Just add the scroll pane not the textarea to the contentPane.  Also set the preferred size of the scrollpane and/or use a layout manager.